# Skip first 4 items/rows in a while loop php

Tags: loops, while-loop

I'm doing a while loop of an object in php.

I'd like to leave first 4 items from the loop.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [for loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php). The value you set for `$i` is the first index that is displayed

```
<?php

$a = array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six');
for ($i = 4; $i < count($a); $i++)
{
    echo $a[$i] . ",";
}
```

Will print:

```
five,six,
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I couldn't. Let me show you the print_r. 
                stdClass Object
(
    [id] =&gt; 2094
    [fields] =&gt; stdClass Object
        (
            [title] =&gt; Port 1
            [tags] =&gt; design, illustration, 
            [url] =&gt; 
            [description] =&gt; 
        )

    [post_id] =&gt; 2116
)

Comment: That is only one object, not an array of objects. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to loop it through. What's the best way to get the properties of the object from the fields mostly?